# Ruby System Call Executing Before Script Finishes

Tags: ruby, erb, pdflatex

I have a Ruby script that produces a Latex document using an erb template. After the .tex file has been generated, I'd like to make a system call to compile the document with `pdflatex`. Here are the bones of the script:

```
class Book
  # initialize the class, query a database to get attributes, create the book, etc.
end

my_book = Book.new
tex_file = File.open("/path/to/raw/tex/template")
template = ERB.new(tex_file.read)
f = File.new("/path/to/tex/output.tex")
f.puts template.result
system "pdflatex /path/to/tex/output.tex"
```

The `system` line puts me in interactive tex input mode, as if the document were empty. If I remove the call, the document is generated as normal. How can I ensure that the system call isn't made until after the document is generated? In the meantime I'm just using a bash script that calls the ruby script and then `pdflatex` to get around the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `File.new` will open a new stream that won't be closed (saved to disk) until the script ends of until you manually close it.

This should work:

```
...
f = File.new("/path/to/tex/output.tex")
f.puts template.result
f.close
system "pdflatex /path/to/tex/output.tex"
```

Or a more friendly way:

```
...
File.open("/path/to/tex/output.tex", 'w') do |f|
  f.puts template.result
end

system "pdflatex /path/to/tex/output.tex"
```

The `File.open` with a block will open the stream, make the stream accessible via the block variable (`f` in this example) and auto-close the stream after the block execution. The `'w'` will open or create the file (if the file already exists the content will be erased => The file will be truncated)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, another approach (less suitable) would be to have `f.flush` after `f.puts`.